# How do I run OpenGL programs using WSL (Ubuntu 20.04)?

Tags: opengl, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using Ubuntu 20.04 wsl2. I'm trying to get OpenGL working. My X11 forwarding works fine but after installing `mesa-utils` and `ubuntu-desktop` and running `glxgears` causes the window to open, but the gears don't move. I get the following error output in the terminal as well

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to set the following environment variable to make the error go away:

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

For a quick test, run:

```
glxinfo -B | grep renderer
```